# Excel TRUE/FALSE IF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a "Pass" column (A) and a "Fail" column (B) in one worksheet. I have a column in another worksheet where I need the following to happen:

- If A is true and B is false, return "Pass"
- If B is true and A is false, return "Fail"
- If both A and B are false, return ""
- If both A and B are true, return ""

I can't figure out the formula that ensompasses all of the above possibilities. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward transformation of
If A is true and B is false, return "Pass" If B is true and A is false, return "Fail" If both A and B are false, return "" If both A and B are true, return ""

I assume the values in Column A and Column B are only Booleans(true/false)

```
 =IF(AND(A2,NOT(B2)),"Pass",IF(AND(NOT(A2),B2),"Fail",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the values in `A` and `B` are only Booleans,

```
=IF(A1=B1, "", IF(A1,"Pass","Fail"))
```

is all you need.